# Continuity under a measure integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \nu)$ is a measure space and that $f=f(x,t) : \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and measurable in $x$ and is continuous in $t$. Define $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$F(t) = \int_{\Omega} f(x,t) d\nu(x).$$
Is $F$ continuous?

Comment: "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus' has  a different meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,t)=\sum g_n(t)I_{E_n}(x)$ where $E_n$'s are pairwise disjoint measurable sets and each $g_n$ is continuous. Then the hypothesis is satisfied and $F(t)=\sum g_n(t)\nu (E_n)$. So to get a counterexample, all you have to do is find continuous functions $g_n$ and positive numbers $a_n$ such that $\sum a_ng_n$ converges but the sum is not continuous. (We can always find disjoint measurable sets $E_n$ with $a_n=\nu (E_n)$. We can take $\nu$ to be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, for example). I will leave this part to you.

Comment: So if that sum converges uniformly, I think we are okay? If we further assume that $|f(x,t)| \leq g(x)$ for every $x, t$ for some integrable function $g$, I think we can appeal to the Dominated Convergence Theorem to get continuity?

Comment: That is a good point. We need something like DCT to prove continuity of $F$ so we have to put some extra conditions. Uniform convergence will do the job if $\nu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: If you can bound $f$ by an integrable function, the result is true by DCT.